# Change font size macvim?

Tags: font-size, macvim

I'm using macvim and I love it. I also happen to really like the default font.

My question is:

How do I change the font size in my .gvimrc? I want it to be bigger, without changing the font from the default.

All the examples I've seen specify a font then a ':' then the size.

So how do I just change the *size* not the *font* itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The default font is [Bitstream Vera](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/source/browse/trunk/runtime/doc/gui_mac.txt?r=292) (search for 'default font' on that page). So why not just specify that, but with a different font size? E.g.

```
:set guifont=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono:h14
```

This approach also ensures that if in future the default changes (e.g. to the system default, `Monaco`), you will still have your preferred font enabled.

Comment: Ah but I figured it out and it was closest to this. Thanks for getting me on the right track. It's `De Ja Vu Vera` on my system. Huh. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: @Alex: That's interesting. Looks like the docs are a little out of date then. This font is an extension of the original `Bitstream` font family, ["to provide a wider range of characters while retaining the original look and feel"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dejavu/). Thanks for coming back with this info.

Comment: On OS X Mavericks this answer does not work.  See @Denis answer, below.  :set guifont=Menlo\ Regular:h16

Answer (score 124):

A quick way to set the font if you don't mind a menu popping up is to type `:set gfn=*`.

This will allow you to adjust any property of the font without changing anything else about it.

Then you can use `:set gfn` to see what it is now set to and add that to your .vimrc.

As an example, in my case it shows `guifont=Monaco:h12` and so in order to get the same setting on startup, I added `set gfn=Monaco:h12` to my .vimrc.

Comment: Thanks for the 'set gfn=*' trick. I really needed to see a list of what was available---good to know I can!

Comment: See `:help gui-font` it includes info about bringing up the font panel.

Answer (score 73):

None of the above answers worked for me, here is what worked out:

**Add to your .gvimrc,   for the janus users its ~/.gvimrc.after :**

```
set guifont=Menlo\ Regular:h14
```

Comment: For subvim create a file: ~/.vim/custom/gvimrc

Comment: You can also add the line in your regular ~/.vimrc

Comment: This worked for me (also none of the above). I also changed ~/.vmrc

Answer (score 63):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> will increase and decrease the font size, respectively.

Comment: I hadd du use Ctrl+Shift+= to increase fontsize. Could be because I use a Norwegian keyboard layout

Comment: @smat Well, this is talking specifically about MacVim on OSX.

Comment: also, we presume if they want to change the font site, then they would like this to be a preference across sessions.  This answer will not do that.

Comment: @Conner Should be Cmd+Shift+= in my above comment. Thank you for spotting the error.

Answer (score 11):

This works great my end.

:set guifont=Menlo\ Regular:h12

Comment: Save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 9):

One useful note is missing from the responses - you can use `set guifont=*` which will bring up a font-picker for you to select from the available fonts on the system. It might be OSX and Linux only, but preferable to having to enter it manually.

Once you've selected the font, you can use `set guifont` again which will print out the name of the font and the size you've selected. The only caveat being that any spaces need to be backslashed in your ~/.vimrc

Comment: Of all the answers this was the one that was the most helpful to me. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 6):

Changing the size in **vim console** font size can increase or decrease

```
set guifont=Menlo\ Regular:h14
```

For **Macvim** following key shortcut work

```
zoom out - CMD+-
zoom in -CMD+=
```

For **Terminal**

```
Zoom in-CMD/ctrl++
Zoom out-CMD/ctrl+-
Normal default size - CMD/cmd+0
```

Comment: yes that's correct. As you zoom in/out, the value of `fontsize` in `set guifont=Menlo\ Regular:h<fontsize>` will increase/decrease accordingly.